# D3.js: Multiple lines within multiple rects

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to draw multiple rectangles based on two timestamps. After that I want to append multiple lines to trim their parent rectangle vertically based on their timestamp. My data looks like this:

```
    var data = [
    {id: "1", 
    timeStart: "22.10.2012", 
    timeEnd: "28.11.2012", 
    intervals: [ timeOne: "23.10.2012", timeTwo: "25.10.2012", timeThree: "25.11.2012"] },
    {id: "2", 
    timeStart: "26.10.2012", 
    timeEnd: "29.10.2012", 
    intervals: [ timeOne: "27.10.2012", timeTwo: "28.10.2012"] },
    {id: "3", 
    timeStart: "29.10.2012", 
    timeEnd: "28.11.2012", 
    intervals: [ timeOne: "23.11.2012"] },
]
```

As you can see the interval arrays can have a varying length and should be used to draw the lines.

My approach would be something like this:

```
  var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data).enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width")
    .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.timeStart); })
    .attr('width', function(d) { return x(d.timeEnd) - x(d.timeStart); })
    .attr('y',foo) //doesnt matter
    .attr('height',bar);  //doesnt matter

 // Now I want to appen each rect its interval array as lines
 rects.selectAll("line")
    .data(...) // What to put here?
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr('x1', function(d) { return x(d.timeOne); }) // But I want also timeTwo, timeThre .., when they exist.
    ...
```

I know about groups (g), but I cant get it done. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Have you seen [the tutorial on nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/)?

Comment: Thanks for your hint! I did something like this with my dataset: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3508/ I assume that I have to convert the timeline object to a timeline array literal to get it via d.timestamp or something like that.

Comment: Well it's certainly much easier if all the keys within the timeline are the same, but you could also use `d3.values()` to get just the values of the associative array: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3509/